# How MS Coded UI Test communicates with browser? Through MSAA?

Tags: browser, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, web-testing, msaa

simple question: **How MS Coded Test UI communicate with browser?**

- I guess tests communicate with browser through MSAA layer, which has the access to controls of the webpage. True?
- But how is it implemented, how the browser exactly do "Click Element"? (I have experience only with selenium and webdriver, which click to a graphic layer.)
- And how is it with cross-browser (only IE and Firefox? [source 2])
- Which test tools also integrate MSAA inside? I know about TestComplete for flash pages (https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/web/flash-flex/approaches/choosing.html ... HP UFT?)

Source (https://www.google.cz/search?q=software+testing+with+visual+studio+2010+levinson+pdf&*, page 136): Automation in Visuol Studio is through three technologies: MSAA, UIA and IE DOM. MSAA is older but still used in web automation.

About web testing and MSAA talks also this source (http://weblab.isti.cnr.it/w3c/talks/2008/wsb08inclusion/k1-gibson.pdf)

I simply cant imagine how it works (even when i saw code). Please answer as simple as you can.